# Ignoring a Invalid XML-Tag using Qdom?

Tags: c++, qt, xml-parsing

I try to parse XML file which contains a attribute tag like this:

```
a="(USA & CANADA)"
```

But i found out that it isn't well-formed XML because the"&" should be URL-encoded (&)

Is there a way to tell QDom to ignore the invalid text to parse the file anyway? Because i can't just fix all XML-files.

I'd greatly appreciate any solutions to this problem.

EDIT: I figured out that there is a function setInvalidDataPolicy(AcceptInvalidChars) but either this doesn't work when using setContent() for the QDomDocument or I'm just using it the wrong way...

```
QDomDocument xmlcontent;
QDomImplementation impl;
impl.setInvalidDataPolicy(QDomImplementation::AcceptInvalidChars);
QFile XMLContentFile(pathString);
xmlcontent.setContent(&XMLContentFile)
```

Anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the implementation using `QDomDocument::implementation()`?

Comment: @DanMilburn When i try to add Elements to my QDomDocument the setInvalidDataPolicy(..) works. But not for the setContent function works fine. but i still search for away to parse my invalid data.... at the moment i try to accomplish it with qXmlStreamReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked my way around the problem.
I now parse the XML file using QXmlStreamReader and when it raises an error I start a own function to fix the XML file. Then a restart my parse routine.
This does the job and I couldn't find a better way to achieve this.