# Correct errors in Doxygen XML output

Tags: xml, qt, doxygen

I am currently writing a parser for the doxygen XML output. Partly for academic reasons and because the code of doxygen/addons/doxmlparser is ancient.

I am using QXmlStreamReader to parse the XML and it raises errors in some attributes. For example the following XML is generated by doxygen:

```
...
<listofallmembers>
...
<member refid="qset_1operator&" prot="public" virt="non-virtual"><scope>libDatabase::Set</scope><name>operator&amp;</name></member>
...
</listofallmembers>
```

This `refid="qset_1operator&"` is of course a problem:

```
XmlStreamReaderError: Expected '#' or '[a-zA-Z]', but got '"'.
```

Other errors include having `<>` characters (and others) in XML attributes.

I know that these characters have to be replaced by their `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc counterparts.

How would I easily (and automatically of course) correct the XML, when I can not use Qt's classes to even look at the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to work around the errors and fix them manually as they appear, iterating over the XML until it is well-formed. See this Stackoverflow question:
[Ignoring a Invalid XML-Tag using Qdom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265366/ignoring-a-invalid-xml-tag-using-qdom/13289398#13289398)

You could also use the [tidy library](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html) to repair the input before processing.